# How to execute powershell script from server1 for deploying wsp in server2

Tags: powershell, wsp

I am trying to remotely deploy wsp file present in server2 by running a powershell script in server1.

I am able to successfully log in to the server2 through server1 using the below command:

```bsh
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString "password" -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential("username",$password)
```

but I am not able to deploy the wsp file. This is the code that I tried:

```bsh
Enter-PSSession -ComputerName server2 -Credential $cred
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Sharepoint.Powershell –EA 0
Update-SPSolution -Identity TechSoup.Web.wsp -LiteralPath "C:\Program Files ...Debug\Some.wsp" -GacDeployment
```

I have also tried to put the above code in a script, save it and run the script remotely.

This is the error that I am getting. I believe it is because I don't have admin privileges, I can say this because when I run the deployment code from server2 as admin, the wsp file is getting deployed. So, how can I get admin privileges remotely. The user has the admin privileges, all I need to do is run it with elevated privileges(like right-click and run as admin, but programatically)

> Update-SPSolution : Cannot access the local farm. Verify that the
>   local farm is properly configured, currently available, and that you
>   have the appropriate permissions to access the database before trying
>   again

**EDIT**

I have tried the below script code in admin mode in powershell:

```
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString "serverpassword" -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential("userName",$password)
Enable-PSRemoting
Enable-WSmanCredSSP -Role Server
winrm set winrm/config/winrs '@{MaxShellsPerUser="25"}'
winrm set winrm/config/winrs '@{MaxMemoryPerShellMB="600"}'
Enter-PSSession -ComputerName Server2 -Credential $cred  -Authentication credssp
```

However, I keep getting this error:

> Enter-PSSession : Connecting to remote server Server2 failed
>   with the following error message : The WinRM  client cannot process
>   the request. CredSSP authentication is currently disabled in the
>   client configuration. Change  the client configuration and try the
>   request again. CredSSP authentication must also be enabled in the
>   server  configuration. Also, Group Policy must be edited to allow
>   credential delegation to the target computer. Use  gpedit.msc and look
>   at the following policy: Computer Configuration -> Administrative
>   Templates -> System ->  Credentials Delegation -> Allow Delegating
>   Fresh Credentials.  Verify that it is enabled and configured with an
>   SPN  appropriate for the target computer. For example, for a target
>   computer name "myserver.domain.com", the SPN can be  one of the
>   following: WSMAN/myserver.domain.com or WSMAN/*.domain.com For more
>   information, see the  about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic

No matter what I try, I get this error. I have tried these techniques:

- Allowed Delegating fresh credentials as well as NTLM fresh credentials in GPEdit.
- I have tried the script present in [This](https://powertoe.wordpress.com/2011/04/29/enable-credssp-from-a-windows-7-home-client/) link
- I have added user privileges in compmgmt.msc at 
  Remote Desktop Users
  WinRMRemoteWMIUsers__
  WSS_ADMIN_WPG
  Remote Management Users

Can anyone suggest any thing ??

Comment: I was making a mistake here: I was `Enter-PSSession -ComputerName server2 -Credential $cred  -Authentication Credssp` running this script on server side. It was meant to run on client side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to run SharePoint commands remotely please follow the steps outlined in: [Remote PowerShell to Manage SharePoint on-premises](https://www.cognillo.com/blog/remotely-manage-sharepoint-on-premises/)

Essentially, after enabling remoting, you have to enable CredSSP access in order for your credentials to be sent to the remote and local computer in order for you to run elevated commands.

On the server:

```
Enable-PSRemoting
Enable-WSmanCredSSP -Role Server
winrm set winrm/config/winrs '@{MaxShellsPerUser="25"}'
winrm set winrm/config/winrs '@{MaxMemoryPerShellMB="600"}'
```

And on the client:

```
Enable-PSRemoting
Enable-WSmanCredSSP -Role Client -DelegateComputer "server2.contoso.com"
```

Then on the client you can enter the session:

```
Enter-PSSession -ComputerName server2 -Credential $cred  -Authentication Credssp
```

Comment: Hi HAL9256. 
Thanks for the advice. Atleast now I know in which direction I have to look upon. I have tried your method. However I am getting this error on server1/remote side:
Enter-PSSession : Connecting to remote server server2 failed with the following error message : The WinRM client cannot 
process the request. CredSSP authentication is currently disabled in the client configuration. Change the client configuration and 
try the request again. CredSSP authentication must also be enabled in the server configuration.
I have edited gpedit.msc and provided necessary delegating fresh cred

Comment: Thnaks for your answer, I was actually making a mistake. :
**Then you can enter the session:**

`Enter-PSSession -ComputerName server2 -Credential $cred  -Authentication Credssp`

I was entering this on server side. I realized what a blunder I was making. Kindly edit your answer such that no one makes this mistake again...

Comment: :-) yes. I have edited the answer to say "on the client" thanks!